# Delayed output to the very end of the output stream in PHP

Tags: php, output-buffering

Say you have a big PHP web application doing echoing, output buffering, etc, all over the place. The end result is a finished HTML/XML document to the browser.

Now say you find yourself in a small function in a random place in a big PHP web application. Is there a simple way to output something, for example an HTML comment, in a way so that it is sent as the last thing to the browser?

Something like a hook for "when everything is finished send this piece of info as well to the browser"?

---

The end goal is basically to output some warnings or debug info in an easy way, without messing up the output.

Comment: Write your own hook that is executed at the end of the execution that displays store stuff and call that.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: Woot!  Forgot that one @MarcB.

Comment: Sometimes this site is like a slower version of google :)

Comment: @MarcB That is indeed right. Thought for some reason that just had to do with crashing! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), which would essentially be the very last thing executed by PHP before terminating your script.